# Visual studio 2010 ultimate won't build the project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Previously, I could build projects and launch the sites..but suddenly, it stopped building and launching them.. I dont know why. It suddenly happened..

What happens is that it builds them , and then it fails to build, therefore, no launch happens..

How do I overcome that problem ..

note: no error message appears...it keeps building, no matter matter how long I leave it to build

Comment: Have you tried to build the project using msbuild from command line? Maybe it's a VS installation problem...

Comment: Please post the build output.

Comment: how do I access the build output?

Comment: Open the window via View -> Output, then select "Build" from "Show output from". Build your project and you'll see output in that window. Please post that output on gist.github.com.

Comment: It is slow and freezes... I succeeded to launch one page only .. it crashes overall.. I cant copy the output even..the whole program freezes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project might be in a very deeply nested folder, sometimes VS have problems compiling projects that exists in a very deeply nested directory.

For example, 
if your project exists in 
**C:\some folder\some other folder\..\few more folders\..\project** then there are chances that VS might not compile the project, even it compiles, it may not be able to show the compile errors' source.

so, the solution,
try to move your project in a simpler and less nested directory, then reload it in VS and try to compile it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i had the same problem and solved that with your answer. thank you. but i will look for another solution because i can not know where the end-user will install my product which search for some dll's called over pInvoke